# VS (Visual Studio) Live share sign in error : Enter user code from the info bar that appears

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I am a beginner to VScode and I recently found the cool feature called `"live share"`.

When I try to sign in to VS Live share, I signed in with Github.

But,

1. VSCode **does not show** my name and just says **"Sign in"** in the bottom bar.
   [image]
2. When Signing in from the browser, `it says` if you are using Linux system click in the link below and it says **"Enter user code from the info bar that appears.**"

[image]

But I can't find where that and how to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "Ctrl+Shift+P" or "F1" and type live share. You should get all the options related to Live share, including sign in and sharing. Hope it works.